# Netplan uses only the first DNS server

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, netplan

I'm trying to configure the nameservers in my `Ubuntu 18.04` with netplan.
I got a DNS server which is running on my localhost (`127.0.0.1`).
My configuration looks like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [172.16.0.1/16]
      dhcp4: 'no'
      dhcp6: 'no'
      gateway4: 172.16.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.8, 8.8.8.8, 10.15.0.18, 127.0.0.1]
  version: 2
```

And when I'm doing an `nslookup` on some DNS name in my env it fails.
The `dig` command is failing too with the `NXDOMAIN` error.

But, when I change the order of the `addresses` in the `nameservers` section to `[127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.8, 8.8.8.8, 10.15.0.18]`, after applying the configuration with `netplan apply` the `nslookup` query works and the `dig` outputs correctly with `NOERROR`.

My question is: why there is any significance to the order of the DNS servers? How can I force the netplan conf to look always in the `127.0.0.1` regarding all\specific domain?

BTW all `netplan apply` are successful without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out- the DNS works with failover only if the DNS server is unreachable or there is a specific configuration in the DNS service to fallback to the next DNS server...

So yes- **there is a significance to the order in the netplan nameservers configuration**.

Comment: However, systemd-resolved is also *sticky* when it fails over to a later DNS server in the list.  So if you list 127.0.0.1 first, and 127.0.0.1 goes down, and resolved falls back to 10.0.0.8, it will *continue* using 10.0.0.8 until restart or another DNS server failure.  So you shouldn't use multiple DNS server addresses in an interface's nameserver section which don't all have the *same view* of names.  Instead you probably want to use per-domain DNS servers as described in `resolved.conf(5)`.